# Bootstrap grid elements overlapping navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build grid elements in which there are two columns and each has a couple of rows of panel elements within them. Everything looks great except for when I scroll my navbar to the point of the grid elements. The elements overlap the navbar like they are floating on top. The weird thing is no other part of the page is doing this, everything is behind the navbar when I scroll except for the grid elements.

Here is an image of the effect I'm seeing:
[image]

Anyone have any idea what is going on? I am also using headroom.js for my navbar.

EDIT: Here is the link to the live website: (link taken down after finding answer, as website still under construction)

Comment: Looks like things are not properly contained. Got a jsfiddle available for us to help you with?

Comment: Emily, please provide the code, a link to the live site, or a fiddle so we can debug and help you.

Comment: I tried fiddle but everyone worked on there fine. I think it might be some components of my page conflicting with each other. I have included the link to the website!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with the navigation's z-index. Even just giving it a value of 1 fixed the overlap for me. FYI, the higher the number the less likely it will be under another element, so you should probably make it something like fifty billion (or 999).

```
.headroom {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes! That did it for me. I kept on trying to alter css for the nav tag instead of the headroom. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No problem. I wouldn't recommend using `z-index: 1` long-term though, higher number equals higher on the z-stack.